# Drilling holes for terminated Ethernet Cable

Tags: ethernet

I have CCTV camera and camera which I’m trying to connect via Ethernet and get both power and data. I would need to drill a hole on the brick wall to pass the Ethernet cable from outside to inside.

The camera is ieGeek IG82 outdoor camera. The reason I wanted to have Ethernet is that it’s more stable than wireless and less chances to get disconnected due signal loss.

My Ethernet cable is terminated. And I don’t know how big is the hole that I need to drill for.

Any suggestions? Or, alternatives?

Comment: don't you have a scrap piece of wood where you can drill some test holes?

Comment: I'd guess not owning drill bits that large, and not wanting to buy a whole range of drill bits that large.

Comment: @Ecnerwal then cut holes in cardboard  ... poke holes in styrofoam ... there are lots of ways to make a hole to test if cable would fit

Comment: Or bring the connector to the store and compare it to the bits...

Answer (score 5):

#### Don't use a terminated Ethernet cable.

Just don't. It never works in the long-term.

Run an unterminated Ethernet cable. Install a jack on each end. Use standard patch cables to get from the camera to one jack and on the other end to get from the other jack to the switch or router.

The hole you need will be on the order of 6mm - 8mm, or ~ 1/4" to 1/3". Figure at least double that diameter (and 4 times the area) for terminated cables to get through.

Answer (score 2):

5/8 inch is the bare minimum. You can fit a terminated cable through a **board** with a hole that size.

To actually get through a **wall**, 7/8 inch is more like it. 5/8 does not leave enough room to get anything to pull the cable with attached without jamming, and walls are generally too thick to just push through.

Yes, that's a huge hole. Suffice to say that a customer had a delusional scope of work, so we followed it while shaking our heads. Whole lotta caulk.

Practically speaking, since weatherproof jacks/plugs are prohibitive, buy exterior rated (for whatever reason, direct burial has been the best search term for those, though I don't advise direct burying them) pre-terminated patch cables twice as long as you need, drill the 1/4 - 5/16 inch hole through the wall for the cable, cut the patch in half (or divide as needed if not half is better), plug into the camera outside and run the cut end through the wall to a jack (or crimp a plug on it.)

Comment: If you do this, definitely better on the "inside" half to punch it down to a jack than to crimp a plug on it.

Comment: Agreed. Punch-down connections are easier and more reliable than crimp, unless you have the right tools and the right experience. And the right tool isn't cheap either. Run installed cables jack-to-jack, and use commercial patch cables to go the last few feet from jack to machine.

Comment: Having all the tools and decades of experience, punchdown connections are more reliable, full stop. Professionally I have a crimper, but I'll choose a factory-crimped patch cable wherever possible. And they are still the part most prone to fail - but they are easily replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The OP no doubt went away and did something or another eons ago, but it's like this for future queries.  The diameter of the plug itself is within a half inch circle.  An RJ45 plug will slide right into the hole in a drill index for a half inch bit... right up to the latch which on my new and improved CAT 8 cable protrudes another quarter of an inch and if your run through the wall is short, such as a plywood shed wall with no insulation, it ought to pass right through a 3/4 inch hole, but the thicker the wall the more chance for snagging up.  With a 3/4 inch hole though you ought to be able to shove it through with something, or pull it through, maybe damaging the latch or maybe not.  You have to have a low opinion of the wall in question to put that big of a hole in it.  I've run an electrical cord through several elevated plywood shed floors but had to drill three interlocking 3/4 inch holes to do so... but I had no regard whatsoever for those floors.  I could have used POE, but I would have had to buy pieces-parts and I had an extension cord that I wasn't using handy, so I just ran it down through one shed floor and up through another.  A brick wall in a residential structure... NEVER... even I wouldn't do THAT!  Either buy the tools and supplies to terminate ethernet or hire someone who has them to do the job for you correctly.  Some crimpers have a wiring diagram right on them... but you may not get it right the first time or even a few after that and really need a tester, too.  Twisted pair that has to be criss-crossed all over before it goes in to be crimped, is easy to do wrong.  With constant practice I'm sure its easy.  As seldom as I do it I have to move slowly and carefully and check and re-check.

Oh, and BTW:  To drill a hole in in masonry of any kind including brick where if possible one goes through a mortar joint, you need either a masonry bit or a "star drill", and to drill through a wall a rather long and expensive masonry bit or "star drill", and I'm not sure that ones going up to 3/4" can be found.  If they can, they aren't common and you will work yourself almost to death making a hole through a brick wall with either.  A "star drill" is really a special asterisk-shaped punch that you beat on with THE RIGHT KIND OF HAMMER and with good eye protection till you make some kind of hole, often a rather messy one.  All in all... get someone who knows what they are doing for that kind of job, too.  A hole just large enough to pass the bare ethernet wire through, is much easier to drill because it's much smaller but I'm not going to say how small because of variations in total thickness of the wire outdoor burial usually being thicker and stiffer, if you need that.